# List groups and members of groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, remote-desktop

I have the following code... it does what I need it to do which is show a list of particular groups and their users but it displays wrong. I get  "group name" this part displays fine then I get Username {user1, user2....} with all the other users missing and the dots instead.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$US = Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -Property Enabled

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*RDS Users' -and Name -ne 'RDS 
Users'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$Table = Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName

        $compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $US -DifferenceObject $Arrayofmembers -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru -Property SamAccountName -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName

        [pscustomobject]@{

            "Group Name" = $Group
            "Name"       = $compare.Name
            "UserName"   = $compare.SamAccountName
        }
  }
  $table
```

Comment: the `$Compare` variable seems to hold a _collection_, so that means `$Compare.SamAccountName` will also hold a _collection_. [*grin*] you need to flatten that ... the usual way would be something like `$Compare.SamAccountName -join '; '`  to give you a semicolon-delimted string.

Comment: set `$formatenumerationlimit = -1`. Then `$table | format-table -auto` at the end of the file instead of just `$table` will help. Displaying as a table will have limitations regardless. `$table | format-list` will show all. If you don't want the collection format (`{item 1, item 2, item 3}`), then you can do what Lee_Dailey says.